# setting value of an input to set $_REQUEST variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I am using a jquery plugin upload, and I want to customize the `delete` file process. So, for some reason, I have to set the `$_REQUEST['file']`. But, the way I manage the upload, I uplaod some file, I get the url of the server. So when I trigger the `delete` `button`, I have no `input` `file` set. So how can I set some input file with the `url` I have so that `$_REQUEST['file']` will not be empty and will carry the right url ?

I tried to set the value of some `.input-delete` I added `<input type="file" class="input-delete">`, `$('.input-delete').val(url);` but then I get this message `InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable`

Edit :

I have this

```
<input type="file" class="input-delete"/>
```

From an ajax request I get some `url`, and as a callback I put

```
('.input-delete').val(url);
```

Comment: Please post more complete code. Not everything, but more than just snippets.

Comment: You can't use a file input to copy URLs. It's an upload widget for the user to select something from their file system and give it to you (voluntarily).

Comment: @IMSoP so I can't set an input file manually ? neither I can set some $_REQUEST['file'] ?

Comment: @user1611830 Where would the file come from? If you could select a random file from the user's computer that would be a HUGE security risk... If it's just a URL, use a text input.

Comment: _Any_ type of input field that you give the _name_ "file" will end up in $_REQUEST under the key `file`, so it could f.e. just be a simple _text_ input field with that name …

Comment: @CBroe I totally overlooked that part of the question. In fact, thinking about it, a file input *wouldn't* end up there, because it would set data in `$_FILE` instead.

Comment: @CBroe I set my input to `<input type="text" name="file" class="input-delete"/>`, but I can't get any ` $_REQUEST['file']` param